# Increment Likes in Objective-C / Parse Cloud Code

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am making a social app using Objective-C and Parse. I am trying to write cloud code to increment likes (which is part of the secured User class) upon a button click. This is what I have as of now:

**Cloud Code**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("incrementLikes", function(request, response) {
               Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
               var user = new Parse.Object("User");
               user.userName = request.params.userName;
               user.increment("profilePictureLikes");
});
```

profilePictureLikes is the name of the database row within the User class that is a number.

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)incrementLikes {
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"incrementLikes" withParameters:@{@"userName": self.user.username}];
}
```

self.user is the PFUser whose profile is being viewed.

This code generates the following error, and does not increment the likes:

```
[Error]: success/error was not called (Code: 141, Version: 1.6.2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error is because you aren't calling the response handler in the cloud code but you have a number of other issues:

1. Not calling the response handler
2. Creating a new user instead of querying to find the existing user
3. Passing the user name instead of the user object id ([see here](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-retrieving))
4. Not saving the user after updating it

Comment: Can you show an example of how this is supposed to be done, or direct me to a link. I'm a beginner in this and there are no good examples. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I am still very confused at the example. I looked at this one as well and still can't quite figure it out: https://parse.com/docs/data#security-cloudcode

Comment: Would you be able to write an example for this incrementing likes through cloud and objective-c? This is the only cloud code I need for my project, the rest of it I figured out through objective-c and parse. Thanks Wain, and I apologize for my beginnerness.

Comment: You need to try adding the query.get part, the save and the response.success and then edit the question of you still have issues

Comment: I would write down a detailed answer with code of what Wain just said, but I think you're better off reading the doc and learning by yourself following Wain's steps. :)